# WebBrowser Copy Image to Clipboard

Tags: c#, .net, browser, clipboard

I'm using a WebBrowser control and want to copy a particular image on the web page to the clipboard. I am aware that I can use the WebBrowser.Document.ExecCommand method to copy the currently selected region of the page but cannot work out how to direct the selection to cover a particular HtmlElement or region of the page.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't write this but found it a while ago and thought it would help you out.

http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3206780/Re-Image-in-WebBrowser.aspx

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2) webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange) ((HTMLBody) doc.body).createControlRange();

foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
{
  imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement) img);

  imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);

  using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
  {
    bmp.Save(@"C:\"+img.nameProp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just for future reference for anyone else using this though - you'll need to add reference to Microsoft.mshtml to your project and add "using mshtml" to your class file.

Comment: @JoeR, thanks for the info, this is pretty old and I haven't used the code in a while but I recalled having it around after reading your question.

Comment: awesome, dude!!

Answer (score 1):

I know it is old but in case someone still looking for it.
if you only want to copy a specific image you can use the following modified version of the code

```
string image_name = "temp.bmp";
IHTMLDocument2 document = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange)((HTMLBody)document.body).createControlRange();

imgRange.add(document.all.item(HTML_IMAGE_ID));
imgRange.execCommand("Copy");
using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
{
      bmp.Save(image_name);
}
```