# How to save dynamic image from WebBrowser control

Tags: c#

I am looking for some way to save dynamically generated image from WebBrowser control. The scenario is I need to login to a website and then there is form containing user data plus one image that's been provided by server upon runtime. I need to process that data after scraping it. This means that I can see that image in WebBrowser control but I can't save it cause it doesn't have any URL. WebClient doesn't seems to be an option out of the box due to login thing. I will have to implement state full communication if I choose webclient to replace WebBrowser control?

The only hurdle is that dynamic image and after brainstorming a lot I am unable to make any progress with it. No matter what way I choose I ended in dead end. I can see WebBrowser control is showing that image so it must have downloaded it somewhere. But for some reason I am unable to figure out where its keeping that image and how can I grab it. I was even wondering to do a silent complete page save but then there is that windows prompt message.

I would really appreciate some suggestions about this.

Comment: You can use Fiddler to determine where the dynamic image is automatically downloaded from. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for help with cracking a captcha.

Comment: I was using fiddler. The thing is image seems to be coming from server include. Separate call to URL was not an option due to login thing. Solution suggested by Justin worked out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This came up a while ago, here is the link

[WebBrowser Copy Image to Clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833718/webbrowser-copy-image-to-clipboard/3833846#3833846)

Comment: Ohh man awesome! It did the trick. Thanks for your spontaneous response. I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 2):

You can render the entire visible contents of the WebBrowser to a `Bitmap` by calling its `DrawToBitmap` method (the method is there and will compile - you just won't see it in Intellisense).  Assuming the server-provided image is in the same place every time, you can then clip just the image out of the full Bitmap.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution that doesn't require copying to the clipboard (Original idea from somewhere in a forum, I can't find the link to give the credit to the original poster)

```
[Guid("3050f669-98b5-11cf-bb82-00aa00bdce0b"),InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),ComVisible(true),ComImport]
interface IHTMLElementRender
{
  void DrawToDC([In] IntPtr hDC);
  void SetDocumentPrinter([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string
  bstrPrinterName, [In] IntPtr hDC);
}

public MemoryStream CopyImage(WebBrowser webBrowser, IHTMLElement3 el, int width, int height)
{
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
  WebBrowser wb = webBrowser;
  IHTMLDocument3 doc = (IHTMLDocument3)wb.Document.DomDocument;
  if (doc != null)
  {
    if (el != null)
    {
     IHTMLElementRender Render = (IHTMLElementRender)el;
     Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(width, height);
     Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm); 
     IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
     Render.DrawToDC(hdc);
     g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
     g.Dispose();
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Render);
     bm.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    }
  }
 return stream;
}
```

example of usage :

```
IHTMLDocument3 docy =(IHTMLDocument3)webBrowser.Document.DomDocument;
var div = docy.getElementById("image");
IHTMLElement3 img = div.children[0];
stream = browsersForm.CopyImage(webBrowser, img, 200, 100);
```