# Mysticism with saving images from the WebBrowser

Tags: c#, browser

All greetings!
use the following code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3833846/407561

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2) webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange) ((HTMLBody) doc.body).createControlRange();

foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
{
  imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement) img);

  imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);

  using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
  {
    bmp.Save(@"C:\"+img.nameProp);
  }
}
```

the code is working properly.
but I have problems with the image that is received, it simply is not updated, and remains so that was saved to a file.
After the page updates all become normal.
What can I do to not refresh a page and get rid of this strange effect?
Thank you in advance for your reply!

Comment: Hard to decode the question, but don't do this until the document is fully loaded.  DocumentCompleted event.

Comment: made a simple circuit http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=3fe94111a5cf346bd395d6f9b416d8b6