# Save GIF image to file from WebBrowser-Control

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io, animated-gif

I have some trouble saving an animated GIF image from a webpage loaded with the WebBrowser-Control in a C#-WinForms application.
Currently I'm just taking a screenshot of the page and crop it down to the location of the animated GIF image but, of course, I just get one frame of it.

Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: What # code have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833718/webbrowser-copy-image-to-clipboard/3833846#3833846