# C# WebBrowser Copy Image to Clipboard-full codes

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am a newer of C#,I want to use WebBrowser control to copy an image and save to local disk,after I googled in stackoverflow is this code I need to use,but I am a newer,could anyone can provider a **Full C# Codes** to make it work?(ConsoleApplication type),thanks in advance.

I want to **COPY** in webbrowser (not download) this image file

[image]

to

C:\google.png

The source is here:
  [WebBrowser Copy Image to Clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833718/webbrowser-copy-image-to-clipboard)

```
string image_name = "temp.bmp";
IHTMLDocument2 document = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange)((HTMLBody)document.body).createControlRange();

imgRange.add(document.all.item(HTML_IMAGE_ID));
imgRange.execCommand("Copy");
using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
{
      bmp.Save(image_name);
}
```

Comment: Your windowsforms solution which you are following works perfectly, I've not used WebBrowser Control within Console based apps, you can follow the tutorial for this purpose. http://www.withoutbugs.com/2010/04/webbrowser-control-in-console-app.html

Comment: Thanks for the help,can you please help me provide a full C# code of  windows form version that you worked perfectly?Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full code of working sample

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
        IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange)((HTMLBody)doc.body).createControlRange();

        foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
        {
            imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement)img);

            imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);

            using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                bmp.Save(@"C:\" + img.nameProp);
            }
        }
    }
```

You need to add namespace `using mshtml;`

Comment: Hi,thanks a lot ,but it seemed threw an error,please see this screenshot:https://i.imgsafe.org/5e5afaba1d.jpg

Comment: I tried to pasted that codes to Form1.cs(is this right?) ,it runs without anything happened,none pictures was saved to my c driver,the screenshot:https://i.imgsafe.org/5ead11b160.jpg

Comment: drag and drop webbrowser control on your form first and remove the declaration of webbrowser.

Comment: Follow your steps,and pressed button1,nothing happend :(  webbrowser control added,the declaration removed,https://i.imgsafe.org/5ee17649d4.png

Comment: 1)Create a new project, select windows forms application
2)Drap and drop web browser control and a button on your windowform
3)double click on button control and paste the code for button
4)There will be a load event, write webbrowser1.navigate code statement there.

Comment: Hi Adeel,I think your code should no problem,that maybe something wrong with my machine,I create new project,as the same,nothing happend.Actually,I just need copy 1 image from my webbrowser,I pasted the codes here,could you please fixed it about "HTML_IMAGE_ID" issue?(VS says,the "HTML_IMAGE_ID"  name does not exsit,how shall I fix it?)The codes here:http://textuploader.com/d1aio The screenshot here:https://i.imgsafe.org/5f35a7545e.png

Comment: Change `imgRange.add(document.all.item(HTML_IMAGE_ID));` here HTML_IMAGE_ID is the ID of the image you want to fetch, you can check the ID of the image by going to source code of link from where you are going to save the image, copy the ID from that page and paste in place of HTML_IMAGE_ID and its a string type. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks so much,I am now very clear,though I was failed saved the pictures,really appreciate!